# Parrot ANAFI drone parameters

Tags: parameters, drone, parrot

I have a project include the use of Parrot ANAFI drone, however I don't have the values of the inertial parameters such as the mass moment of inertia (I_x,I_y,I_z) only the mass is known.

Can you please provide me the values of these parameters if anyone worked with such drone before?
Or can you guide me to a source that enables me to get the values?

Thanks in advance!